# ASP.NET routing: http://mywebapp/##ID## to http://mywebapp/Custs/Customer.aspx?id=##ID##

Tags: asp.net, url, routes, parameters, redirect

I'd like to redirect the URL hxxp://mywebapp/**##ID##** to hxxp://mywebapp/Custs/Customer.aspx?id=**##ID##**.
What is the easiest way using ASP.NET 3.5 routing to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: a google search "asp.net url rewriting", can find you many ways.

Comment: Done, but: too many ways! I wanted a little help to sort ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solutions that works.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/

http://urlrewriter.net/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlrewriter.aspx

Select one get use it.